# Java: How to get nth letter of words in a String array

Tags: java, arrays, return

I am required to write up a static method named getSuccessiveLetters(words) that takes a string array and returns a single String. If the String array is {"hello", "world"}, then the program should return "ho". "h" is from the first word, "o" is the 2nd letter from the 2nd word and so on.

I managed to get the correct return value for {"hello", "world"}, but if the String array contains, for example,{"1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "fifth"} it goes out of range it struggles.

```
public class Template01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getSuccessiveLetters(new String[]{"1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "fifth"})); 
    }

public static String getSuccessiveLetters(String[] words) {
    char Str[] = new char[words.length];
    String successive;
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        successive = words[i];
        if (i < successive.length()){  
            Str[i] = successive.charAt(i);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    successive = new String(Str);
    return successive;
}
```

I expected the return value to be 1nd, but the actual output is 1nd\x00\x00.

Comment: build a String, each iteration, myStriing += string.charAt(i); and catch any exceptions

Comment: why 'h' is not included (in your expected result - `1nd`) from "fifth" - cause after  'd' from "3rd" it stopped adding letters because of the there is no letters in available in "4th"?

Comment: The issue is that the 4th entry of your array (value `4th`) does not contain 4 chars. That's why the line `Str[i] = successive.charAt(i);` fails in this case. You should add a check on the length of `words[i]`.

Comment: @Razib Yes, once it reaches the 4th it stops and skips the rest, therefore not returning the 'h'

Comment: @user430574 So the requirements actually say the "h" should not be outputted? i.e. stop as soon as we find a string that's too short? That's quite rare, IMO.

Comment: @Sweeper I would have thought so too, but gotta do what it tells me to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because when you initialize a char array, it fills the array with the default char value.
You can use `StringBuilder` or `List<Character>` to grow your "array" with each addition.

Change

```
char[] str = new char[words.length];
```

to

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
```

and

```
str[i] = successive.charAt(i);
```

to

```
str.append(successive.charAt(i));
```

and then at the end `successive = str.toString();`.

Comment: The return output should be limited to 1nd, but the "fifth" 'h' is also being printed.

Comment: @user430574 works fine for me. Let me update the answer with the full code.

Comment: I got rid of the break statement. Once I added it back on, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you ignore the strings in the original array that are not long enough, you are not setting some of the char array elements as a result. This means that some elements will have the `char` value of `\0` (default value of `char`). The resulting string therefore has these extra `\0` characters as well.

I think it is more suitable to use a `StringBuilder` rather than a `char[]` here:

```
public static String getSuccessiveLetters(String[] words) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String successive;
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        successive = words[i];
        if (i < successive.length()){  
            builder.append(successive.charAt(i));
        }
        // you should not break here, because there might be a longer string in the array later on.
        // but apparently you don't want the "h" in "fifth"? Then I guess you should break here.
    }
    successive = builder.toString();
    return successive;
}
```

Comment: Nice edit, thank you so much for the help. The break in the else solved everything.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Unit-Tests here. This could help you to improve.

you are creating a charArray here:

```
char Str[] = new char[words.length];
```

this array has the length of your string-array

```
new String[]{"1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "fifth"}
```

which is 5

you create 3 entries for your new array (because you break at the first word, which is too short)
therefor you get 3 letters "1nd" and the 2 other slots in your array are filled with blanks when calling

```
successive = new String(Str);
```

1st: think about the break statement
2nd: think about using a StringBuilder / StringBuffer instead of a char[] for your matches

imho the most correct result should be **1nd h** - but this depends on your given task